# Generic of Templates Error

Tags: c#, generics

I'm attempting to make a list of templated classes, passing in a base class to the template. It seems however, that this isn't allowed. Is there a way to circumvent this restriction, or restructure my code more appropriately?

Here is an abstract example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TempInherit
{
    abstract class Shape{}

    class Triangle : Shape{}
    class Square : Shape{}

    class ShapeHolder<T>{}

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // list of base class, add subclass - works
            List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
            shapes.Add(new Triangle());
            shapes.Add(new Square());

            // list of holders of base class, add holders of subclass - fails
            List<ShapeHolder<Shape>> shapeHolders = new List<ShapeHolder<Shape>>();
            shapeHolders.Add(new ShapeHolder<Triangle>());
            shapeHolders.Add(new ShapeHolder<Square>());
        }
    }
}
```

Which yields:

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List>.Add(TempInherit.ShapeHolder)'
>   has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (TempInherit)
>
> Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`
>   TempInherit.ShapeHolder' expression to type
>   `TempInherit.ShapeHolder' (CS1503) (TempInherit)

Comment: can you provide more code about ShapeHolder<T> and Shape?

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi: I've added my full code, but it is just a little sample that mimics the error I'm having in my real application. I'm sure it's from my misunderstanding of C# Generics, as I'm an iOS / Android developer playing with Xamarin.

Comment: The reason is ShapeHolder<Triangle> is not treated as inheriting from ShapeHolder<Shape>

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

covariance problem :

You may create an interface `IShapeHolder<out T>`, as generic parameters on interfaces can be covariant (but not on classes)

something like that

```
public class Shape
    {
    }
    public class Triangle : Shape
    {
    }
    public class Square : Shape
    {
    }
    //T generic parameter is covariant (out keyword)
    public interface IShapeHolder<out T> where T : Shape
    {
    }
    public class ShapeHolder<T>  : IShapeHolder<T> where T: Shape
    { 
    }
```

then,

```
var shapes = new List<Shape>();
shapes.Add(new Triangle());
shapes.Add(new Square());

// list of holders of base class, add holders of subclass - fails no more
var shapeHolders = new List<IShapeHolder<Shape>>();
shapeHolders.Add(new ShapeHolder<Triangle>());
shapeHolders.Add(new ShapeHolder<Square>());
```

Comment: Note to the questioner, this disallows retrieving items from the `shapeHolder`. But this is intended by design, otherwise you could be inserting `Square`'s into a `ShapeHolder<Triangle>` by casting that to a `ShapeHolder<Shape>`.

Comment: @Josh Fine if it helps, but read the comments carefully, they are significant drawbacks !

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: My ShapeHolder<T>s are actually FeedManager<T>s, that are responsible purely for downloading their respective RSS feed, and marshalling the XML into the type of the generic parameter, so there is no need for me to retrieve the item in the 'holder', merely iterate over then.